# How to make it extremely easy to run a python script for a user

Tags: python, bash

I built a python/bash application for OSX that I want to distribute to non techsavvy users. My problem is how to get the user to initially run my python script. The script sets up a cron job so the user never has to do anything again but the user MUST run it the first time. The issue is that python and bash scripts default to non-executable when unzipped. As of now I have instructions in the readme.txt for the user to open the terminal and copy and paste the command which chmods the script and runs it for them. However is there anyway I can accomplish this without having the user open the Terminal? Ideally the user could just double click the python script and have it run. Thanks.

Comment: What operating system(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Good question, I'll add it to the description.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes being user-friendly warrants using platform-specific features.  In this case, the Mac OS X "Installer" system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_(OS_X)

Rather than a .zip file, you can create a .pkg file which users can download and install just as they would any other program native to OS X.  This should give them a familiar experience, and you can make the .pkg file do what you need behind the scenes.